# ssh to host using python

Tags: python-3.x, ssh

I would like to use a python code to automate the ssh to another Host and send the password, Does anyone know how to do this.
I try to to ssh to another host using following code:

```
import os , shutil , glob , subprocess , sys
from subprocess import run, PIPE

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','-t','admin@192.168.1.34'], stdin=PIPE)
proc.communicate(input='password')
```

The first line works properly and does ssh to Host but second line is unable to send the password and I get following Error:

```
proc.communicate(input='password')
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 828, in communicate
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 781, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Did you try sending a `bytes` object instead of a string?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, meant to include a link in the previous comment: [`bytes` Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects).

Comment: is there any way to send string? Thanks